# running other class than main.c in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, class

I'm learning C although I've already learned Java. Since I'm on a Mac, I've downloaded Xcode to write my C code. (I really enjoy an IDE rather than just use a notepad to write my code).

I have some exercice to do. So I create a new Project Called Homework and I thought I could do all my different exercise in this project!

So ,in Xcode, I've created a new C project. I have a main class. Now what I want is to create a new class and run it. The problem is that Xcode alway run the main.c class. How do I create a new class in a project and Run this class ? (not the main class). 
Or is this not possible and I have to create a new Project every time I want to run a new classe ??

(i.e with Eclipse for Java : You create a project and inside you can create multiple class and run then independently.)

Can you help me ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You'll need separate projects. There are no classes in C, but every program needs a `main` function to run, and you can only have one in any single program.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple build targets and `#ifdef` in the correct `main()` depending on the build target.

For example, if you go to `Build Settings` and find `Preprocessor Macros`, and add a macro `ASSIGNMENT1`you could create a build target called `Assignment1`.

For your 2nd assignment, you could create an `Assignment2` target and add an `ASSIGNMENT2` preprocessor macro.

Then, in your `assignment1.c`, you could have:

```
#ifdef ASSIGNMENT1
int main(int argc, char* arv[]) {
    ...
}
#endif
```

And in your `assignment2.c`, you could have:

```
#ifdef ASSIGNMENT2
int main(int argc, char* arv[]) {
    ...
}
#endif
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that any functions will share a namespace. If you aren't sharing code between projects, it will probably make more sense to create separate projects.